# Error after converting android.net.Uri to java.io.File

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, retrofit2

I am trying to write logic to upload an image, using Retrofit2 and Jetpack Compose. When creating a File object from the image's Uri, the File object seems to have `content://` scheme instead of `file://`, which is causing `FileNotFoundException` while creating the request object for Retrofit2.

For example, the below code throws IllegalStateException.

```
fun upload(imageUri: Uri) {
    val file = File(imageUri.path!!)
    if (!file.exists()) {
        throw IllegalStateException("File $imageUri does not exist.")
    }
    ...
}
```

The exception is as below:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: File content://media/external/images/media/1000000363 does not exist
```

Note that the Uri is valid, and I'm able to use it to display the image in the UI.

I have tried creating the `File` object in different ways, such as `imageUri.toFile()`, which throws:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Uri lacks 'file' scheme: content://media/external/images/media/1000000364
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use the uri directly. Open an inputstream for the uri and give the stream to Retrofit. Do not use File class. Google for inputstreamrequestbody.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed by issue by using InputStream as described in [this article](https://gutier.io/post/android-upload-file-to-aws-s3-bucket-with-retrofit2/)